# Modalpopup wont close when dropdown is selected

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, modalviewcontroller

I've been having this odd issue with modal popups. For some reason when I choose a dropdown item my update button wont fire a click event. but then I leave the dropdown at their default values the update button works just fine.

here's my aspx page code

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="hide" runat="server" Text="Button" />

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="cfPopUp" PopupControlID="Panel4"
    TargetControlID="Button1" OkControlID="cfUpdateBtn" CancelControlID="cfCancelBtn" />
<asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="Server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel13" CssClass="" runat="server">
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel14" CssClass="" runat="server">
                    <div style="padding: 10px; border: 3px solid black; background-color: White; color: Black;">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label25" Width="200px" runat="server" Text="Health and Safety Net" /><div
                            class="seperator">
                        </div>
                        <table class="style143">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="style185">
                                    <asp:Label ID="cfCategorylbl" runat="server" Text="Category:"></asp:Label>:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cbFactors_Categories" runat="server" Width="350px" Font-Names="Tahoma"
                                        Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="DimGray" Height="24px" CssClass="style75">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDown3" runat="server" TargetControlID="cbFactors_Categories"
                                        Category="categories" ServiceMethod="getCategory" ServicePath="~/2012/IrSubmitWebService.asmx"
                                        PromptText="Select Category" />
                                </td>
                                <td align="center" rowspan="3" valign="top">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblFactor_ID" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small"
                                        ForeColor="DimGray" Style="font-style: italic" TabIndex="56"></asp:Label>
                                    <cc1:DynamicPopulateExtender ID="lblFactor_ID_DynamicPopulateExtender" runat="server"
                                        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="lblFactor_ID" BehaviorID="dp1" ServiceMethod="getFactorID"
                                        ServicePath="~/2012/IrSubmitWebService.asmx">
                                    </cc1:DynamicPopulateExtender>
                                    <hr class="style157" />
                                    <asp:Label ID="cfID" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="DimGray"
                                        Style="font-style: italic" Width="400px" TabIndex="57"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="style185">
                                    <asp:Label ID="cfTypeslbl" runat="server" Text="Type:"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cbFactors_Types" runat="server" ForeColor="DimGray" Height="24px"
                                        TabIndex="54" Width="350px" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" CssClass="style75">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="cbFactors_Types_CascadingDropDown" runat="server"
                                        TargetControlID="cbFactors_Types" ParentControlID="cbFactors_Categories" Category="type"
                                        ServiceMethod="getTypeofAction" ServicePath="~/2012/IrSubmitWebService.asmx"
                                        PromptText="Select Type">
                                    </cc1:CascadingDropDown>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="style185">
                                    <asp:Label ID="cfFactorslbl" runat="server" Text="Factor:"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cbFactors_Factors" runat="server" ForeColor="DimGray" Height="24px"
                                        TabIndex="55" Width="350px" Font-Names="tahoma" Font-Size="Small" CssClass="style75">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="cbFactors_Factors_CascadingDropDown" runat="server"
                                        TargetControlID="cbFactors_Factors" ParentControlID="cbFactors_Types" Category="category"
                                        ServiceMethod="getFactor" ServicePath="~/2012/IrSubmitWebService.asmx" PromptText="Select Factor">
                                    </cc1:CascadingDropDown>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="style185">
                                    <asp:Label Text="Justification:" ID="cfJustificationlbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtJustification" runat="server" ForeColor="DimGray" Height="29px"
                                        Style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: small" TabIndex="56" TextMode="MultiLine"
                                        ToolTip="Provide a justification for this factor." Width="775px" Font-Names="Tahoma"
                                        Font-Size="Small"></asp:TextBox>
                                   </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <br />
                        <div style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:Button CausesValidation="false" ID="cfUpdateBtn" runat="server"
                                Text="Update" CssClass="button" /><span style="margin-left: 10px"><asp:Button CausesValidation="false"
                                    ID="cfCancelBtn" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="button" /></span></div>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

and my code behind for my update (it just closes the popup)

```
Protected Sub cfUpdateBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cfUpdateBtn.Click
    cfPopUp.Hide()
End Sub
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why the update button wont work when the dropdowns are not the default value.

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: do you run your code without using ajax cascading dropdownlist may be it work

Comment: I dont believe it to be the cascading dropdownlist, I have other modal popups with cascading dropdowns and it works perfectly. Thanks for looking at my issue.

Comment: ok, try one more thing u have bind your dropdown with a web service. If you add items manually ( means hardcode ) to your dropdown still it does not work ?

Comment: That did work. so why can't I use cascading dropdowns with a webservice? are they not meant to work together?

Comment: I don't know exactly why it is not working but may be when you select an item on dropdown, the web service is called if it is called may be your page again loads. So you have to check the behavior of webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically rebuilt my modal popup and update panel like so

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlEditPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlEditPopupContent" runat="server">
            <div style="padding: 10px; border: 3px solid black; background-color: White; color: Black;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="name">Category:</td>
                <td class="value">
                    <asp:DropDownList id="ddCat" runat="server">
                        <asp:listitem value="">No Selection</asp:listitem>
                        <asp:listitem value="Action">Action</asp:listitem>
                        <asp:listitem value="Worksite">Worksite</asp:listitem>
                        <asp:listitem value="Human Factors">Human Factors</asp:listitem>
                        <asp:listitem value="System Factors">System Factors</asp:listitem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name">Type:</td>
                <td class="value">
                    <asp:DropDownList id="ddType" runat="server" />
                    <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="ccType" runat="server"
                        TargetControlID="ddType"
                        ParentControlID="ddCat"
                        PromptText="No Selection"
                        LoadingText="Please Wait..."
                        ServicePath="~/2012/IrSubmitWebService.asmx"
                        ServiceMethod="getTypeofAction"
                        Category="Other"
                    />
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td class="name">Factor:</td>
                <td class="value">
                    <asp:DropDownList id="ddfactor" runat="server" />
                    <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="ccFactor" runat="server"
                        TargetControlID="ddfactor"
                        ParentControlID="ddType"
                        PromptText="No Selection"
                        LoadingText="Please Wait..."
                        ServicePath="~/2012/IrSubmitWebService.asmx"
                        ServiceMethod="getFactor"
                        Category="Other"
                    />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Justification:
                    <asp:Label ID="factorID" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtJustification" runat="server" ForeColor="DimGray" Height="100px"
                    Style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: small" TabIndex="56" TextMode="MultiLine"
                    ToolTip="Provide a justification for this factor." Width="300px" Font-Names="Tahoma"
                    Font-Size="Small"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    Factor ID<br />
                    and Description:             
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="factor_id_Desc" runat="server" Width="300px" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small"
                        ForeColor="DimGray" TabIndex="56"></asp:Label>
                    <cc1:DynamicPopulateExtender ID="DynamicPopulateExtender1" runat="server"
                        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="factor_id_Desc" BehaviorID="dp1" ServiceMethod="getFactorID"
                        ServicePath="~/2012/IrSubmitWebService.asmx">
                    </cc1:DynamicPopulateExtender>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnOkEditPopup" runat="server" Text="Ok" CssClass="button"/>
                    <span style="margin-left:10px"><asp:button id="btnCancelEditPopup" runat="server" text="Cancel" CssClass="button"/></span>
                </td>
            </tr>

            </table>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>

    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>

    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeEdit" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="btnOpenEditPopup"
        PopupControlID="pnlEditPopup"
        />
```

Fixed my issue. I still dont know why it wasn't working when I asked the question but I was able to solve it. Thanks to all who looked into it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason may be you are binding your dropdownlist with a webservice. Whenever you click to an item on dropdownlist webservice may be called. If webservice is called then may be your page again loaded ? I don't know the exact reason why it is not working. You have to check the service behavior what happened when the service is called.

Comment: since its a ajax control the page doesn't reload. the web service makes it asynchronous. I've been searching online and this should be possible to accomplish.

Comment: ok if you found the solution then also share it with us and one more thing the asp dropdownlist works with the web service or not also check it.